# How to call a class that accepts command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line

I am not a good programmer.  In school, I learned MATLAB.  So i have no idea what I am doing.

I am working with the ThingMagic M6 reader.  They have their own API.  I wanted to create my own application to read the program.  I want to use a sample program that they have supplied (since my program doesn't seem to work).  However, the supplied program only accepts command line arguments.  How do i change it so I can pass arguments to it in my code.

This is the supplied code:  (at the command line I input tmr://10.0.0.101)

```
    /**
 * Sample program that reads tags for a fixed period of time (500ms)
 * and prints the tags found.
 */

// Import the API
package samples;
import com.thingmagic.*;

public class read
{  
  static void usage()
  {
    System.out.printf("Usage: demo reader-uri <command> [args]\n" +
                      "  (URI: 'tmr:///COM1' or 'tmr://astra-2100d3/' " +
                      "or 'tmr:///dev/ttyS0')\n\n" +
                      "Available commands:\n");
    System.exit(1);
  }

   public static void setTrace(Reader r, String args[])
  {    
    if (args[0].toLowerCase().equals("on"))
    {
      r.addTransportListener(r.simpleTransportListener);
    }    
  }


   static class TagReadListener implements ReadListener
  {
        public void tagRead(Reader r, TagReadData t) {
            System.out.println("Tag Read " + t);
        }
  }

  public static void main(String argv[])
  {

      System.out.println(argv.getClass().toString());
    // Program setup
    TagFilter target;

    Reader r;
    int nextarg;
    boolean trace;

    r = null;
    target = null;
    trace = false;

    nextarg = 0;

    if (argv.length < 1)
      usage();

    if (argv[nextarg].equals("-v"))
    {
      trace = true;
      nextarg++;
      System.out.println("Trace");
    }

    // Create Reader object, connecting to physical device
    try
    { 

      TagReadData[] tagReads;
      r = Reader.create(argv[nextarg]);
      if (trace)
      {
        setTrace(r, new String[] {"on"});
      }
      r.connect();
      if (Reader.Region.UNSPEC == (Reader.Region)r.paramGet("/reader/region/id"))
      {
          r.paramSet("/reader/region/id", Reader.Region.NA);
      }
      r.addReadListener(new TagReadListener() );
      // Read tags
      tagReads = r.read(500);
      // Print tag reads
      for (TagReadData tr : tagReads)
        System.out.println(tr.toString());

      // Shut down reader
      r.destroy();
    } 
    catch (ReaderException re)
    {
      System.out.println("Reader Exception : " + re.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception re)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + re.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

This is me trying to use it: (arg comes from a JTextField)

```
String[] argv = new String[1];
        argv[0] = arg;
readOnceApp(argv);
```

I have a feeling there is a really simple answer to this problem, I just can't figure it out.  I searched the internet for a few days and read books, and still can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

edit: readOnceApp is one method I wrote.  It is basically just the main method of the supplied code.  I can include it, if it will help. I just didn't want to post too much code.

Comment: What's readOnceApp? An object of "read" class? Try calling read.main(argv) instead. It's a static method so you don't need to instantiate the class.

Comment: @Tom That didn't work unfortunately.  I tried passing the input to it in several different ways, and still it didn't work.  If read works from the command line, is there a reason it won't work when I call it within my program?

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the "main" method of a class from another class, do it like this:

```
String [] args = new String [1];
args[0]= "some param";
readOnceApp.main(args);
```

This is making the assumption that "readOnceApp" is the name of your class.  (BTW, you should follow the convention of using capitalized class names, e.g. ReadOnceApp).

Hope this helps.